# I added style for dataGridCell, but when I try to find it, exception is appearing that style didn't find

Tags: c#, wpf

In the code there are two styles which I want toggle in the DataGridColumn "CreationDateDisplayer". DataGrid have two conditions which are described by the type CurrentDisplayingListTypes. Method ToggleCurrentDisplayingList successfully change condition of DataGrid.

I want change column styles when DataGrid condition is changed. I try to change style in the code "CreationDateDisplayer.CellStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("Default") as Style;", but "FindResourse" don't find style.

(I removed code which can't be related with my problem)

```
        <Window.Resources> 
               <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="Default">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="CreationDate" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}" x:Name="RecordingList">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d92525"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Window.Resources>
            <Grid>
               //some button which method is "ToggleCurrentDisplayingList"
               <DataGrid x:Name="RecordingsDisplayer">
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CreationDateDisplayer" CellStyle="{StaticResource CreationDate}"/>
            <Grid>
    </Window.Resources>
     
  
        private void ToggleCurrentDisplayingList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (currentDisplayingList)
            {
                case CurrentDisplayingListTypes.RecordingList:                   
                    RecordingsDisplayer.ItemsSource = basket;                    
                    CreationDateDisplayer.CellStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("Default") as Style;
                    currentDisplayingList = CurrentDisplayingListTypes.Basket;
                    break;
                case CurrentDisplayingListTypes.Basket:          
                    RecordingsDisplayer.ItemsSource = recordingList;
CreationDateDisplayer.CellStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("CreationDate") as Style;
                    currentDisplayingList = CurrentDisplayingListTypes.RecordingList;
                    break;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: You should add what type of exception is thrown and the message displayed. Where do you use the line that throw the exception relative to the xaml ? Is it in the code behind (xaml.cs) file ?

Comment: it is in the xaml.cs in a binding method to button

Comment: exception is that FindResource("Default") can't find style

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting so it's easier for someone who wants to answer. Add more code to show exactly where you define the style in the xaml relative to this `CreationDateDisplayer` control. The most likely explaination is that the declaration of the style isn't in the right scope so it can't be found but I can't give a good answer with the code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.Current.FindResource("Default") will perform search starting from Application.Resources.

By the look of things, "Default" Style is defined close to DataGrid, so use DataGrid's own [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=net-5.0) method

```
CreationDateDisplayer.CellStyle = RecordingsDisplayer.FindResource("Default") as Style;
```

> If the resource is not found on the calling element, the parent element in the logical tree is searched next, then the application, then themes, and finally system resources.

since ge it directly from window Resources:

```
CreationDateDisplayer.CellStyle = this.Resources["Default"] as Style;
```